# Google Apps Script: "Missing ';' before statement"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

Today is my first day using Google Apps Script.  I am trying to make a script to grab weather information from the Wunderground Api and paste it into a spreadsheet.

For some reason I am getting the error message "Missing ';' before statement. (Line 34)".
I've searched for a solution but cant find why I am getting this error in my code.

```
//Everyday this script gets weather data from Weather Underground and records it in this spreadsheet.

cDay = 0, cTemp = 1, cHumidity = 2, cPressure=3, cSparkline=4, cConditions=5;
nCols=7;

function getTemp() {

  var url = 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/' + appKey + '/conditions/q/CO/Aspen.json';
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

  var contentText = response.getContentText();
  var conditions = Utilities.jsonParse(contentText);
  var todaysConditions = conditions;

  var temp = todaysConditions.current_observation.temp_c;
  var humidity = todaysConditions.current_observation.relative_humidity;
  var pressure = todaysConditions.current_observation.pressure_in;
  var conditions = todaysConditions.response.features.conditions;  

  sheet.insertRowAfter(1);
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,1,1, nCols);
  var row = range.getValues()[0];

  var d = new Date;
  var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
  var day = d.getDate();
  var year = d.getFullYear();
  var hour = d.getHours() + 1;
  var minutes = d.getMinutes();

  row[cDay] = month + '/' + day + '/' + year + '' + hour + ':' minutes; //here is the error
  row[cTemp] = temp;
  row[cHumidity] = humidity;
  row[cPressure] = pressure;
  row[cConditions] = conditions;
  var nRows = numRows >= 10 ? 10 : numRows;
  //row[cSparkline] = "=SPARKLINE(R[0]C[-3]:R[" + (nRows-1) + "]C[-3])";
  range.setValues([row]); 

}
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the '+' sign

row[cDay] = month + '/' + day + '/' + year + '' + hour + ':' + minutes;

Comment: it happens to everybody sometime :)